# Injective functions from $\mathbb C$ to $\mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that all bijective holomorphic functions $f \colon \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ takes the form $f(z) = az+b$. But what about the set of injective holomorphic functions from $\mathbb C$ to $\mathbb C$?

Comment: Do you know how to prove the result you have claimed? From the very proof you will see that these are also the only injective ones. Basically you need the singularity at infinity to be a pole or removable singularity to be injective, hence the function is either constant or a polynomial. Now apply the fundamental theorem of algebra

Comment: Yes. Upon reviewing the proof, I realized that all three cases are looking for contradictions specifically in injectivity. Hence, the result shall be the same. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly! Glad to be of help